# Unable to make general purpose query, without Domain entity

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I am new to springbootneo4j. I have difficulties making general purpose queries. I want to be able to make any kind of query and get result without domain entity.

I am making a query like this in repository class:

```
@Query("MATCH (p:Employee) RETURN ID(p) as id, p.name as name, p.salary as salary ")
```

that is not working, but the following query is working:

```
@Query("MATCH (p:Employee) RETURN p ")
```

My domain entity class is something like this:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;

    @Relationship(type = "IS_BOSSOF", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED) Set<Employee> reporties = new HashSet<>();

    public Employee() {}

    // some more code
}
```

Create a command is like this:

```
(laksmi:Employee{name:"Laksmi",salary:200}),(ashwini:Employee{name:"AshwiniV",salary:300}),  (harish:Employee{name:"Harish",salary:400}),  (jay)-[:IS_BOSSOF]->(mukesh),   (xyz)-[:IS_BOSSOF]->(mukesh),    (harish)-[:IS_BOSSOF]->(ashwini),
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are distributing properties you need to use @QueryResult annotation on your class
[SDN](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#reference)